# std::shared_ptr::reset() "invalidates" other references

Tags: c++, opengl, shared-ptr

All my code is single-threaded at this time.

I have a texture manager that owns a collection of "texture collections" which in turn hold, "own" and manage all my game's textures as `std::shared_ptr's`. One collection is dedicated to my framebuffer textures. At initialization, it instantiates all my framebuffer textures, and later, a separate framebuffer object requests them all and stores its own `std::shared_ptr` references to these textures. I use this object in my deferred renderer. No problem so far: looking at the debug information in Visual Studio (2015), it shows two strong references (the one in the collection, and the one in the framebuffer object) per framebuffer texture; working as it should.

The problem arises when my window dimensions change. I listen for the `WM_SIZE` event, and upon a resize, my WndProc calls the following (again, on the references in my framebuffer texture collection, rather than my framebuffer object -- adhering to my ownership convention):

```
void PantheraTextureCollectionFramebuffer::Resize( unsigned int width, unsigned int height ) {
    _textures["depth"].reset( new PantheraTexture( width, height, PantheraTextureFormat::Depth24,
            PantheraTextureMinFilter::Nearest, PantheraTextureMagFilter::Nearest ) );

    _textures["diffuseSpecular"].reset( new PantheraTexture( width, height, PantheraTextureFormat::RGBA8,
            PantheraTextureMinFilter::Nearest, PantheraTextureMagFilter::Nearest ) );

    _textures["normalParallax"].reset( new PantheraTexture( width, height, PantheraTextureFormat::RGBA8,
            PantheraTextureMinFilter::Nearest, PantheraTextureMagFilter::Nearest ) );

    _textures["position"].reset( new PantheraTexture( width, height, PantheraTextureFormat::RGB16F,
            PantheraTextureMinFilter::Nearest, PantheraTextureMagFilter::Nearest ) );

    _textures["uvMaterial"].reset( new PantheraTexture( width, height, PantheraTextureFormat::RGB16F,
            PantheraTextureMinFilter::Nearest, PantheraTextureMagFilter::Nearest ) );
}
```

Which recreates all the textures with the new window dimensions. *BUT*, the `std::shared_ptr's` in the framebuffer object remain unchanged (apart from the ref counts for each texture, which drop to one). It seems I've fundamentally misjudged `std::shared_ptr` and its `reset()` method.

I've also tried reassigning using indirection, for example:

```
*_textures["depth"] = PantheraTexture(...)
```

which, aside from feeling unpleasantly hacky, doesn't call my texture objects' destructors and so OpenGL never frees the invalid textures.

I am stumped. I'd like to keep the texture objects immutable themselves, otherwise I'd probably implement an internal Resize method for them, leveraging glTexImage*D. How would you suggest going about maintaining continuity between my texture collection and my framebuffer object without resorting to that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you've created a `shared_ptr`, copied that pointer to a framebuffer object, and then you call `.reset()` on the *original* pointer, and it doesn't update the copy?  Unless I misunderstand what you are saying, that sounds like exactly what `shared_ptr` is supposed to do.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you can also use `make_shared()` to initialize your pointers.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I do use make_shared when first instantiating. Your first comment hits the nail on the head, but this is where my difficulty is. I want to change (well, replace) the underlying object that the shared_ptr owns, and have all other existing references point to it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the way to handle this is for you to stop using `shared_ptr` for things that don't really *own* objects.

For example, you have a `PantheraTextureCollectionFramebuffer`, which I assume represents a collection of textures that are used by a framebuffer. This object *owns* those textures; it manages when they are created, recreated, and destroyed.

Elsewhere, you presumably have some `Framebuffer` class. Right now, it has `shared_ptr`s to the textures it uses, which represents ownership over those textures. But does it *really* own those textures?

Not really. Now yes, if you share ownership between them, then you can destroy the collection while still using the framebuffer. But... would you really *want to*?

No. Logically, if you have destroyed the collection, the framebuffer that uses that collection should *also* have been destroyed, right? But at the same time, perhaps a framebuffer can use textures from multiple collections.

In that case, I would say that a framebuffer should claim ownership over any collection that it gets one or more of its images from.

Furthermore, these collections seem to be groups of named images. As such, users would presumably refer to textures by name, getting the actual texture object from their collection(s) as needed.

Therefore, collections need to know who owns them so that, if a texture is updated or modified, they can be informed of this. At the very least, this framebuffer collection class needs to tell any framebuffers that reference it when a texture is being updated, so that they can reinitialize whatever data they need to.

> which, aside from feeling unpleasantly hacky, doesn't call my texture objects' destructors and so OpenGL never frees the invalid textures.

Then you must not have employed the Rule of Three/Five correctly in your type. You allowed it to be copyable, but you didn't implement copying behavior correctly.

You should make your type non-copyable, since implementing proper copying behavior for a texture wrapper is not a good idea.

Comment: Hi Nicol, your answer steered me on the right track. I was decidedly not adhering to the Rule of Three, thanks for pointing that out. I implemented it, and this has given me the correct behavior when I assign through indirection. I appreciate your other suggestions, but I would like to keep my framebuffer texture collection agnostic to my framebuffer objects; FB objects will provide their attributes (e.g. width, height, format) by referencing the texture properties. This way, only one system is responsible for the FB textures. Thanks again for the solution!

Comment: Forgot to mention that I also understand now why storing shared_ptrs in my framebuffer objects could end up being an issue. I'm modifying it to store weak_ptrs instead.